# Using SUMIFS or FILTER to sum with text and date criteria, in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

I am really stuck trying to sum a value using multiple filters, one for text, and one for the year.

I have tried two different formulas.

```
=SUMIFS('Libya civcas LIVE duplicate'!AD:AD, 'Libya civcas LIVE duplicate'!L:L, "*GNA*", 'Libya civcas LIVE duplicate'!B:B, "*2012*")
```

I thought `SUMIFS`would work but I can't get it to recognise the year as the range it formatted as date not plain text. So I tried without luck the option below:

```
=SUM(FILTER('Libya civcas LIVE duplicate'!$AC$2:$AC,YEAR('Libya civcas LIVE duplicate'!$A$2:$A)=2012), REGEXMATCH("*GNA*", 'Libya civcas LIVE duplicate'!$K$2:$K))
```

The data I am working with looks like the following:

```
(Column A)
DATE
13/09/2012
10/08/2013
11/08/2013
20/08/2013

(Column K)
BELLIGERENTS
LNA/GNC
GNC
Unknown

(Column AC)
STRIKES
2
2
1
3
```

Help much appreciated. If you need further details just ask!

Answer (score 3):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=sumifs(AC$2:AC, K$2:K, "*gnc*", A$2:A, ">="&date(2012, 1, 1), A$2:A, "<"&date(2013, 1, 1))
```

[image]

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

```
=SUMIFS(AC:AC, K:K, "*gnc*", A:A, ">="&DATE(2012, 1, 1), A:A, "<"&DATE(2013, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You always use `Sumproduct()` to handle multiple criteria.  For this data:

[image]

We calculate the sum of strikes for "birds" on 12 June 2018 using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A25=DATE(2018,6,12))*(K2:K25="bird")*(AC2:AC25))
```

I believe `Filter()` is only supported in google-spreadsheets.  From your example, it appears that you also want to apply wildcards to one of the criteria.  To do this with `Sumproduct()`, use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A25=DATE(2018,6,12))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("bird",K2:K25,1)*(AC2:AC25)))
```

Comment: I think `(A2:A25=DATE(2018,6,12))` is supposed to be `(YEAR(A2:A25)=2018)`

Comment: @Jeeped  You are correct.  My formula looks for a specific date.